# What is the overall take of Hinduism on menstruation?

Tags: scripture, practice, culture, tradition, women

One of the debated topic related to Hinduism is menstruation and related matters. There are some texts including smritis which seem to depict menstruation with antipathy.

In some of the regions and communities it is something like a taboo even today. Whereas some communities and regions are liberal about it. 
I want to know what exactly is the overall view of Hinduism on this subject?
With respect to scriptures as well as traditional, social, and cultural aspects.

There are various threads on this forum regarding women and entry in temples during menses and performance of pooja during menses etc. ?

What are the various views on this subject from religions, scriptural and cultural point of view ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is also a belief that menstruation was not initially happening in women but it started as a result of sin of Indra which was shared by women. However, then a bigger question arises. **What about other mammalian species of animals and birds which exhibit this phenomenon?** So it looks like menses is not a later day phenomenon but a part of human physiology since the beginning which is also supported by Ayurveda.

**Vedas were indeed silent** on this because, this being a natural phenomenon, nobody thought it fit to raise such issues. But the extra-vedic literatures like smritis and the extra- Upanishads think otherwise. Let us see what the smritis have to say about menses:

Aangirasa smriti & Aapasthamba smriti (as also quite a few other smritis) say that **Prathamehani caandaali dviteeye brahmaghatini trteeye rajakee proktha caturthe hani shudhyati**

A woman in the first day of her courses is known as an outcaste, in the second day murderer of a Brahmin, in the third day she is known as a washer woman and on the fourth day she gets purified!

You know how a woman should conduct herself during these days? 
Vyaasa smriti

> Sarvairalakshitaa sheeghram lajjitaantargrhe vaset|
>
> ekaambaraavrtaa deena snaanaalankaara varjitha ||
>
> mouninyadhomukhee chakshushpaani padbhirachanchalaa |
>
> ashneeyaath kevalam bhaktham naktham mrnmaya bhaajane ||
>
> Unseen by everybody, she with lajja should at once go to the
>   antargrham (cow shed?). She should wear only one cloth throughout. She
>   should avoid bathing and decorating herself. She should not speak, her
>   face should be downwards looking, her eyes and limbs totally
>   immobilized. She should not eat. Eat she must only in the night, food
>   cooked in an earthen vessel!
>
> Svaped bhoomau apramattaa kshapedevamahastrayam |
>
> snaayeetaa saa triraatraante sachailamuditeravou ||
>
> vilokhya bhartrvadanam shudha bhavati dharmatah |
>
> krtaa shouche puna: karma purvavachhasamaacaret ||
>
> She should lie down on the floor and fast for 3 days. After the end of
>   3 nights she should bathe with her dress at sunrise. Thereafter, after
>   seeing her husband’s face, she becomes pure!
>
> Udakyaayah karenaatha bhungtvaa chaandraayanam chareth –  If one
>   happens to eat food cooked by a menstruating women, one should perform
>   the chaandraayana vow.

After seeing a women in her courses if one takes his food, he should immediately vomit it and then drink water purified by kusa grass.

Now let us see other contrary views related to this in the scriptures.

**Temples and menstruation:**

> The [Ambubachi Mela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambubachi_Mela) is an annual Hindu mela held at Kamakhya
>   Temple in Guwahati, Assam. This yearly mela is celebrated during the
>   monsoon season that happens to fall during the Assamese month Ahaar,
>   around the middle of June when sun transit to the zodiac of Mithuna,
>   when the Brahmaputra river is in spate. It is the celebration of the
>   yearly menstruation course of goddess Kamakhya. It is believed that
>   the presiding goddess of the temple, Devi Kamakhya, the Mother Shakti,
>   goes through her annual cycle of menstruation during this time
>   stretch.[2](http://www.drnorthrup.com/celebrating-a-girls-first-period/) It is also believed that during the monsoon rains the
>   creative and nurturing power of the 'menses' of Mother Earth becomes
>   accessible to devotees at this site during the mela. There is no idol
>   of the presiding deity but she is worshipped in the form of a
>   yoni-like stone instead over which a natural spring flows.
>
> There is another temple in Kerala, The remarkable aspect of this
>   Bhagwati temple at Chengannur is that the phenomenon of the goddess
>   getting her periods still continues even though the deity is cast in
>   the five metals (panchaloha) The temple therefore follows a unique
>   ritual where the chief priest or his assistant (kizhusanti) on opening
>   the Srikoil early morning removes the nirmalyam (previous day's
>   decoration of the deity) and hands it over to the Varrier attendant
>   along with the white udayada (petticoat) without looking at it. The
>   Varrier examines the dress closely and if there are signs of bleeding
>   sends it to Thazhamon Matham, the traditional residence of the temple
>   Tantri. There the lady of the house scrutinises the cloth again and
>   confirms the menses.The udayada, after the occurrence of the menses is
>   available for sale to the public. Though the rate fixed by the
>   Devaswom is only Rs. 10/- due to its being a rarity it is grabbed by
>   devotees by paying hundreds of rupees who book it well in advance

**Cultural and traditional point of view:**

In many south Indian and East Indian states, the **first menstruation** of the girl is celebrated by the family. It is known as **ritushuddhi** or ritu kaala samskara.

> [Ritushuddhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ritushuddhi) is a Hindu samskara associated with a girl’s first
>   menstruation. Hindus in India tend to view first menstruation or
>   menarche, as a positive aspect of a girl's life. This samskara is
>   usually the 13th of hindu samskara. For boys, a similar samskara is
>   conducted which is called keshAnta samskAra (first shaving of the
>   beard).
>
> This milestone in a girl's life is observed by her family and friends,
>   with gifts and her wearing a sari for the ritual.The rite of passage
>   is celebrated, in modern times, as a "half-saree party" where the
>   female relatives and friends of the girl gather, and she receives and
>   wears a half-saree and other gifts. Thereafter, at ceremonious events,
>   she wears the half-sarees, until her marriage when she puts on a full
>   sari.
>
> In the state of Orissa, Menstruation and womanhood is celebrated every
>   year in a very grand manner as a four day fest across the state.
>
> Raja or **[Raja Parba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raja_(festival))** or Mithuna Sankranti is a three-day-long
>   festival and the second day signifies beginning of the solar month of
>   Mithuna from, which the season of rains starts. It inaugurates and
>   welcomes the agricultural year all over Odisha, which marks, through
>   biological symbolism, the moistening of the sun dried soil with the
>   first showers of the monsoon in mid-June thus making it ready for
>   productivity
>
> It is believed that the **mother goddess Earth** or the divine wife of
>   Lord Vishnu undergoes menstruation during the first three days. The
>   fourth day is called as Vasumati gadhua or ceremonial bath of Bhudevi.
>   The term Raja has come from Rajaswala (meaning a menstruating woman)
>   and during medieval period the festival became more popular as an
>   agricultural holiday remarking the worship of Bhudevi, who is the wife
>   of lord Jagannath. A silver idol of Bhudevi is still found in Puri
>   Temple aside Lord Jagannatha.
>
> During the three days women are given a break from household work and
>   time to play indoor games. Girls decorate themselves with new fashion
>   or traditional Saree and Alatha in feet. All people abstain from
>   walking barefoot on earth. Generally various Pithas are made of which
>   Podopitha,and Chakuli Pitha are main. People play a lot of indoor and
>   outdoor games. Girls play swings tied on tree branches whereas aged
>   ladies play Cards and Ludo. Many villages organise Kabbadi matches
>   among young men.

Apart from Indian culture, the first menses are also celebrated in various **cultures of the world** such as:

> • The Nootka people of Canada had a big party right after a girl’s
>   first period. Then she underwent an endurance ritual in which she was
>   taken far out to sea and left to make her way home by swimming back to
>   land. When she arrived onshore, she was greeted by her entire village.
>
> • Among the Dagara people of West Africa, the initiation of girls is
>   performed once per year for all the girls who have started to
>   menstruate in the preceding year. This ceremony is the beginning of a
>   long period of mentoring that includes information about sex,
>   intimacy, and the special healing powers of the menstruating woman.
>
> • Many Navaho people still practice their puberty ritual for girls,
>   the kinaalda. According to menstrual researcher Lara Owen, this is
>   considered to be the most important of all their rituals because it
>   brings new life to the tribe. In the month after a girl gets her first
>   period, her entire extended family gathers together for a ceremony
>   that takes place over four days.

[Source](http://www.drnorthrup.com/celebrating-a-girls-first-period/)

**Ayurveda**:

> From Ayurvedic point of view, among various basic principles and
>   physiologies described in Ayurveda **Rutuchakra** i.e. Menstruation. 
>   Various terms are used in classic to denote menstrual blood and ovum
>   at different places ie. Artava, Raja, Shonita, Lohita, **Pushpa**,
>   Bija. Also has mentioned role of Doshas on menstruation i.e. like all
>   other physiological processes menstruation is also governed by three
>   Doshas viz. Vata, Pitta and Kapha.
>
> Rutukala- This phase is mainly influenced by Kapha. It is a period of
>   resembling proloferative phase.
>
> • Rutuvyatita-kala- This phase is influenced mainly by Pitta.
>   Therefore this phase resembles the secretory phase.
>
> • Rajahsrava-kaala- This phase is mainly influenced by Vata. Vata
>   always act through Dhamanees. In the phase of menstruation the spasm
>   in the straight stem arterioles as a causative phenomenon of bleeding
>
> Ayurveda has also given mode of living in menstruation. Right from the
>   beginning of menstrual flow, Woman should observe Brahamacharya
>   (sexual abstinence), She should avoid cold bath, Should not sleep
>   during day time, should avoid exertion. Her diet should be light. The
>   female is also advised to live in a happy calm mood.

[Source](http://www.ayurlog.com/Archive/january_march/ssac/201502S060.pdf)

**Scriptural point of view:**

> LXXI. — Soma gave them **purification**; the Gandharva, sweet speech;
>   Agni, perfect purity; therefore **verily women are always pure**. —
>   Yajnavalkaya smriti 71.
>
> Women (possess) an **unequalled means of purification**; they
>   **never** become (entirely) foul. For month by month their temporary uncleanness removes their sins. (Vashistha Dharmasutra 28.4)
>
> Women belong first to three gods, Soma (the moon), the Gandharva, and
>   Fire, and come afterwards into the possession of men; according to the
>   law **they cannot be contaminated**. (Vashistha Dharmasutra 28.5)
>
> Soma gave them cleanliness, the Gandharva their melodious voice, and
>   Fire purity of all (limbs); therefore **women are free from stains**
>   (Vashistha Dharmasutra 28.6)
>
> Pure is the mouth of a goat and of a horse, pure is the back of a cow,
>   pure are the feet of a Brâhmana, **but women are pure in all
>   (limbs)**. (Vashistha Dharmasutra 28.9)

[Source](http://www.hinduwebsite.com/sacredscripts/hinduism/dharma/vash4.asp#ch28)

Scriptures also say that the process of menstruation also cleanses their acquired sins and impurities in this monthly process.

The optional Vedic sacrifices, the Pashuyaga, Soma sacrifice etc. are barred in the absence of wife. If she is absent in the sacrifice due to monthly periods she would get all the fruits of the sacrifice. KAtyAyaya, however, mentions that if she attains menses during the soma sacrifice, she should continue wearing her Deeksha garments, stay in the sand during the emission, and should finally take her baths on the fourth day before the altar during the morning and evening.  (samskAra paddhati 1, 20-21).

SamskAramaYukha quotes vrrdha-gArgya to show that the vrriddhi shraddha may be performed by her **even during the monthly cycles**.

However, **Agamas (shakta) have a different perspective** which is quite opposite to those found in some of the smritis and related literature.

From shAktagamic point of view, menstruation is not viewd as something inauspicious or impure but is actually celebrated and also considered embodiment of auspiciousness/sanctity.

They are very clear about their views on woman and their divinity.

In both Kulachudamani Tantra and the Brihad Nila Tantra, the Kaula (sAdhaka) is instructed to recite a mantra inwardly whenever he sees a woman.

In **mAtrikabheda tantra**, the menstrual discharge is looked upon as something very powerful and divine.

**Matrikabheda Tantra**

(English translation Indological Book House 1990) describes the different types:--

> "Lord Shankara said: The first menses appearing in a woman who has
>   lost her virginity is **Svayambhu** blood. In a maiden born of a married
>   woman and begotten by another man, that which arises is **Kunda** menses,
>   the substance causing the granting of any desire.
>
> Deveshi, a maiden begotten by a widow gives rise to Gola menses, which
>   subdues gods. The menses arising in the first period after a virgin
>   becomes a married woman is the all bewildering **Svapushpa**."  (MT,
>   Patala 8)
>
> The very first chapter of the MT mentions a substance called **sambal**,
>   described in the commentary as a woman's menstrual discharge. This
>   substance allows the tantrik adept to perform various sorts of
>   **alchemical** operations.

Further, kankAlamAlini tantra also mentions use of menstrual discharge (swayambhu) for making kavacha (for protection).

[Source](http://www.scarletwoman.org/scarletletter/v2n4/v2n4_yoni1.html) 
[Source](https://divinetantrictouch.com/yoni-tattva-in-kaula-tantra/)

**To conclude**, it looks like as such there is not much in the Vedic literature against menstruation. Further, agamas also do not have any taboo with respect to menstruation. Even cultural festivals and temples have positivity related to menses. So the anti-menses quotes in some extra-vedic scriptures could be later interpolations. It is also a topic of research about the contradicting views of such scriptures. As such the main texts do not criticize menses and participation of menstruating women in social/religious activities.

They are asked to avoid painstaking activities if they are not comfortable. However, it should be made as a rule that all women should avoid every activity. It should be decided by them if they want to participate or not. If they wish to do something it should not be forbidden. After all, in the present day we have all hygienic measures and sanitation etc.

Comment: "there is not much vedic literature against menstruation." - You are wrong. You don't know about this from krishna yajur veda: https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/yv/yv02.htm | Also, many dharma shastras discuss the impurity of menstruation.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Late reply to say thx for posting this like five years ago ! :) I very much agree w/ the Shakta texts views of menstruation, what you’ve quoted from the Matrikabheda & Kankalamalini Tantras here. Excellent. Thx :D

Comment: @Ikshvaku there are interpolations also in dharma shastras. If  you see grihya or shrauta sutra you won't find such things there.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi What is your evidence this was interpolated when it is in the Krishna Yajur Veda?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi I don't have complete knowledge of the grhya/shrauta sutras, but it this is also mentioned in the Purva mimamsa sutras.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Not just dharma shastra even mahabharata at many places talks about menstruation rules plus we have a case study of draupadi periods. Also verses quoted in your answer are out of context - celebration/ritual of menses doesn't imply purity of gross body e.g. when a person dies, there are death rituals but these rituals don't make a dead body pure to touch. Death/menstrual rituals are for subtle body, spirits etc. Also goddess menstruating is different from human menstruating eg: vishnu sleeps on cobra bed but this doesn't mean humans also have to sleep on cobra bed.

Comment: The only thing which Vedas/smriti don't mention (to my knowledge) is putting a menstruating women in cowshed. This is a practice which is not from scriptures and can be debated as this is very risky for woman's life due to threats from rats, snakes, wild animals etc.

Comment: @ArvindC I have also quoted smritis and other texts both in positive and negative way. If draupadi was so impure then no one would have looked at her or touched her if they were following dharma sutras

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Please see Shabara swami's commentary: https://archive.org/details/ShabaraBhasyaTrByGanganathJha/Shabara%20Bhasya%20tr%20by%20Ganganath%20Jha%20Vol%201/page/n521/mode/1up?view=theater&q=women

Comment: @RakeshJoshi  "If draupadi was so impure then no one would have looked at her or touched her if they were following dharma sutras" - dushashan, duryodhana etc. are not role models for morality as mahabharata describes them as evil incarnation of kaliyuga. Draupadi was immorally summoned to court and then forcibly dragged when she refused. Mahabharata mentions at many places that dharma rules were violated during this incident.

Comment: @ArvindC ya but it also shows that many things are interpolation like treating in cowshed. The only thing for them is take rest and vrata. But later it became a bad thing

Comment: @RakeshJoshi - as I mentioned in my earlier comment, cowshed is not mentioned in smriti texts, so there is no reason to blame smriti texts here. It may have been a superfluous introduction by a fanatic person. Hope we are done with this discussion.

Comment: @ArvindC I have already quoted the verses in initial part of my posts. I didn't ask for any discussion with you. I just responded to your comments

Answer (score 1):

taittiriya yajur veda II - [PRAPATHAKA V](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/yv/yv02.htm) gives details of prohibitions during women periods:

> *'Let us choose a boon; let us obtain offspring from after the
> menses; let us enjoy intercourse at will up to birth.' Therefore women
> obtain offspring from after the menses, and enjoy intercourse at will
> up to birth, for that was what they chose as a boon. They took a third
> of his guilt, it became (a woman) with stained garments; therefore
> **one should not converse with (a woman) with stained garments [5], one should not sit with her, nor eat her food, for she keeps emitting
> the colour of guilt**. Or rather they say, 'Woman's food is unguent,
> and there fore **one should not accept (from her) unguent**, but
> anything else (can be accepted) at will.' The son born of
> intercourse with (a woman) with stained garments is accursed; (the son
> born) of intercourse in the forest is a thief; (the son born) of
> intercourse with a (woman) who turns away is shamefaced and retiring;
> (the son born) of intercourse with a woman bathing is fated to drown;
> (the son born) of one who [6] anoints herself has a skin disease; (the
> son born) of one who combs her hair is bald and feeble; (the son born)
> of one who anoints (her eyes) is blind; (the son born) of one who
> cleans her teeth has dirty teeth; (the son born) of one who cuts her
> nails has bad nails; (the son born) of one who spins is a eunuch; (the
> son born) of one who weaves ropes is unrestrained; (the son born) of
> one who drinks from a leaf is drunken; (the son born) of one who
> drinks from a mutilated (vessel) is mutilated. For three nights he
> should keep a vow and should drink from his hand or from a perfect
> vessel, to guard his offspring.*

[brihadaranyaka upanishad 6.4.13](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe15/sbe15097.htm) also give prohibitions:

> *13. When the monthly illness seizes his wife, sheshould for three days not drink from a metal vessel, and wear a fresh dress. Let no Vrishala
> or Vrishalî (a Sûdra man or woman) touch her. At the end of the three
> days, when she has bathed, the husband should make her pound rice .*

Comment: This one is translated by western scholars right?

Comment: She’s gotta pound rice ? What.

Comment: Samwell Tarly: "The White Walkers sleep beneath the ice for thousands of years. And when they wake up..."
Pypar: "And when they wake up... what?"
Samwell Tarly: "I hope the Wall is high enough."
— Samwell Tarly talks about the Wall.....Blame Castle Black :-)

Comment: This is the right answer Arvind.

Comment: Arvind as a vegan types I fully agree w/ all your meat/fish posts on here, I’m so glad you post those :) On this though, I think I’m more inclined w/ the Shakta views, so we could agree to disagree on the menstruation thing :D

Comment: Still don’t get this though : “ At the end of the three days, when she has bathed, the husband should make her pound rice .” Not sure what it means for husband to make his wife pound rice. (?) I don’t understand the first paragraph either actually, if the lady bathes or combs her hair, has clean teeth and nails, her son will be messed up ? Or maybe it means not to be intimate with a lady while she is bathing, combing hair, fixing nails, etc ? Isn’t that self-explanatory though, no one has sex while brushing teeth or fixing their nails.

Comment: @Miss In traditional Vedic Brahmin families, when the woman is in menstruation, she should not do those things listed like taking a bath, combing her hair, etc.

Comment: @Ikshvaku Oh. Ok. I didn’t know that. Thx for explaining. Not able comb hair, take a bath, brush teeth for several days sounds horrid. Can’t imagine making a woman in modern times do that, especially with school, work, kids, cooking, etc. I’m much more a fan of the Tantra views on this topic. Anyway thx for explaining, that first paragraph is easier to understand now :)

Comment: @Miss I have added a comment on Shakta verses that you referred. It is a misconception that scriptures are anti-women. There are rigid  rules for men as well like brahmacharya discipline for 12-36 years. 3 day rule for women is nothing in front of this. There is no gender inequality in these scriptures, they follow an equity concept

Comment: @ArvindC brahmachara is for both. Please refer to my post on brahmacharya. I am just showing there's not anti gender stuff in the vedas

Comment: @ArvindC Oh thx, I will read and take a look. In general I appreciate the detailed  discussion on all these topics on here, being able to hear the different viewpoints etc. It would be quite boring if we all agreed on everything anyways :D

Comment: @RakeshJoshi - yes it is for both but in my comment I was referring to disciplinary side of brahmacharya for men i.e. deer skin, gurukul, etc. which are not part of brahmacharya for women

Comment: @ArvindC women also resided at gurkula i have mentioned some examples in answers elsewhere. They also learned vedas and shastra. How did draupadi learn vedic scriptures?

Comment: yes shastras mention women education from guru (father/husband) but this is going off topic, I can discuss this in a relevant post.