# Can a lady undergoing menstruation period do yoga?

Tags: scripture, yoga, women, menstruation

I heard that a lady undergoing menstruation should not do yoga.

My doubt is can a lady during her menstruation do yoga or not? 
If no then after how many days she can be able to do yoga?
If yes, then what type of asanas she can do?
Is it explicitly mentioned anywhere?

Comment: If its mild asanas or prAnayAma then it can be done. Difficult postures not recommended

Comment: After 4 days...

Comment: No, and after her period ends.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the overall take of Hinduism on menstruation?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21014/what-is-the-overall-take-of-hinduism-on-menstruation)