# Can a woman attend marriage ceremony during menstrual cycle?

Tags: marriage, women, menstruation

Suppose a woman gets her menstrual cycle during the marriage day of her sibling, can she attend the marriage ceremony?

It is well known that she should not touch and involve in work related to marriage. But I am not sure whether she can attend the marriage as a visitor.

I searched the internet and many other forums related to Hinduism, but nowhere I found any logical or direct answer based on the scriptures of Sanatan dharma.

Comment: I don't know about different regions/states following customs practices related to this. However, I can say from a TamBrahm perspective, she cannot attend the event.  the wedding is a `vedic ritual` based holy event, and thus she cannot attend unfortunately.

Comment: During those 3 nights she is to be excluded from everything (see answers in this forum). Marriage is no exception.

Comment: menstruating women are not supposed to touch anyone who blesses the couple with manthra-akshatha (turmeric rice). since it is very hard to attend a marriage and not accidentally touch someone who might bless the couple, they are not to attend the marriage. nowadays if you tell women this, they would argue back about scientific cleanliness, pads, tampons etc. - all because they believe they have financial freedom and power to override shastras. women who disrespect shastras are no different from men who disrespect shastras - both are to be looked down upon and shunned with prejudice.

Comment: Not allowed as per veda - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/53248/21696